# ActiveAndroid setup

Tags: java, android, activeandroid

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to use SQLite with Active Android ORM.  I have a simple todo app and I'm following the tutorial to setup active android. However, it doesn't tell you where to actually put your model files.

https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Getting-started

I believe I have my AndroidManifest.xml setup correctly, I don't know where to put the class where you actually setup your models.  This snippet was provided in the tutorial but I don't know where it goes

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeLibraryApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

Also, do I create a  new file in app/java/com.blahblah and declare my tables there?

Any help on how to structure this would be appreicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple really. After you've added your application class, make sure to add it to your manifest:

> ```
> <application
>     ***android:name=".MyApplication"***
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
> ```

As for where you put your models, it doesn't matter really. You can have a following structure:
[image]

Just make sure to add any of your model classes to manifest. Here's how my manifest would look for above structure:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> package="com.example.dbtest" >
>
> <application
>     android:name=".MyApplication"
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>     <activity
>         android:name=".MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>
>     <!-- Set a name for your database -->
>     <meta-data android:name="AA_DB_NAME" android:value="SomeDatabaseName.db" />
>     <meta-data android:name="AA_DB_VERSION" android:value="5" />
>
>     <!-- All of your models (tables) go here, separated by coma -->
>     <meta-data
>         android:name="AA_MODELS"
>         android:value="com.example.dbtest.models.Item, com.example.dbtest.models.Category" />
>
> </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

I think that's all there is to it.